# How do I start a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In Java I can extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable`, what is the equivalent in C#? I find only something which looks little bit like implements runnable, but nothing usefull.

Comment: Why do you want to mimic the java's behaviour in c#. Read about TPL

Comment: You should ask, "how do I start a thread in C#" if you want an actual answer.  Also, you shouldn't be starting threads directly all that often.  In most cases you should be using the thread pool or dealing with `Task` objects (which will deal with threads under additional layers of abstraction).

Comment: No, you can't do this.
Why don't you look at the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't extend `Thread` in C# - and you generally shouldn't in Java either. (You should just implement the `Runnable` interface.)

Instead, if you want to start to start a new thread, you create an instance of either the `ThreadStart` delegate or the `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate, and pass that into the constructor for `Thread`.

Here's a short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart action = Count;
        Thread thread = new Thread(action);
        thread.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    static void Count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Secondary thread...");
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }        
    }
}
```

For more information on delegates, see [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

For more about threading, see [Joe Albahari's threading tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

To be honest, these days you should usually be using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` instead - try to use higher-level abstractions than just raw threads.

Comment: But Count does not return anything.

Comment: @Robert There is an implicit conversion from any method group (note the lack of parenthesis on `Count`, it's not being *called*) to a delegate with a matching signature.  `ThreadStart` is a delegate for a method that takes no parameters and returns nothing; `Count`'s signature is the same.

Comment: But what if i want my static method return a double?

Comment: @Servy  I would like to create Thread which has a method which returns a frequency of sound as double.

Comment: @Robert: What does it even mean to create a thread which returns a value? Note that you wouldn't be able to do that in Java either (using `Thread` directly). You *can*, however, create a `Task<double>` using the Task Parallel Library in .NET 4. It's like a `Future<Double>` in Java, but with more features. As for the delegate part - please read the links in the answer.